# Have $formatters be called when view is first populated?

Tags: angularjs

`NgModelController` provides `$formatters` for model -> view transformations. I am playing with it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_nth/vKzUW/1/). It works fine after I make changes to the model through another input, but my formatter isn't called when the value is initially populated. Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever the $modelValue changes, all the $formatters are called.  So after the call to read(), set the $modelValue to kick the $formatters to run:

```
read();                    // initialize
ngModel.$modelValue = '';  // causes $formatters to run
```

See also [this google group post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/cvHU-AUOP4U/wDahiSxuljIJ).