# Angular.js formatter not being fired on modelValue change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, formatter

http://plnkr.co/edit/HN1PBGRsK6xqT9pwXcKY?p=preview it should be quite self explaining

`ctrl.$formatters` runs when I initially set the model value, but don't after I update it.

According to this [Have $formatters be called when view is first populated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995414/have-formatters-be-called-when-view-is-first-populated) it should fire everytime model value is changed, so what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the natural model setter, `scope[attrs.ngModel]` instead of setviewvalue.

```
app.directive('format', function($filter) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    element.unbind('input').unbind('keydown').unbind('change');
        element.bind('blur', function() {
            if (element.val()) {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope[attrs.ngModel] = element.val();
                });         
            }
        });

        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(modelValue) {
            if (modelValue) {
                var formatted = $filter('currency')(modelValue);
                return formatted;
            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

You will also need a parser for this to work correctly.

Comment: darn, what if ng-model is something like ng-model="entry.test" though.. it's inside ng-repeat you know..

Comment: just do a attrs.ngModel.split(".") and then iterated through the scope properties

Comment: @foxx @roemer then you'd probably want to add ngModel to isolated scope via bidirectional binding which puts it in scope, i.e. `$scope.ngModel =` OR you can do the slightly hackier `$scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel)`

Comment: What is meant by "You will also need a parser for this to work correctly."?